# I can't understand the behaviour of btrim()

Tags: postgresql, trim

I'm currently working with postgresql, I learned about this function `btrim`, I checked many websites for explanation, but I don't really understand.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) they mention this example:

```
btrim('xyxtrimyyx', 'xyz')
```

It gives `trim`.

When I try this example:

```
btrim('xyxtrimyyx', 'yzz')
```

or

```
btrim('xyxtrimyyx', 'y')
```

I get this: `xyxtrimyyx`

I don't understand this. Why didn't it remove the `y`?

Comment: What part of _"Remove the longest string consisting only of characters in `characters` (a space by default) from the start and end of `string`"_ don't you understand?

Comment: The first and last characters of the string in your second example (which both happen to be x) don't exist in the list of characters to be trimmed so trimming stops there and nothing is trimmed.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith for the reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs you point to, the definition says:

> Remove the longest string consisting only of characters in characters
>   (a space by default) from the start and end of string

The reason your example doesn't work is because the function tries to strip the text from **Both** sides of the text, consisting **only** of the characters specified

Lets take a look at the first example (from the docs):

```
btrim('xyxtrimyyx', 'xyz')
```

This returns `trim`, because it goes through `xyxtrimyyx` and gets up to the `t` and doesn't see that letter in `xyz`, so that is where the function stops stripping from the front.

We are now left with `trimyyx`

Now we do the same, but from the end of the string.
While one of `xyz` is the last letter, remove that letter.
We do this until `m`, so we are left with `trim`.

*Note: I have never worked with any form of sql. I could be wrong about the **exact** way that postgresql does this, But I am fairly certain from the docs that this is how it is done.*

Comment: What I missed is that the operation is done character by character from both sides, if the 1st character in any side isn't in the list so the operation stops in that side. so thank you @Jebby

Comment: You are welcome. It was a learning experience for the both of us as I've never played around with sql before. I just had a quick look at the docs you provided.

Comment: Try `SELECT btrim('DDuDucDuckDuckGockDu', 'Duck')`, it returns `Go`.